# Android device connected to mysql server

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, database

I am currently working on a android app that needs to download everything from an online mySQL database, all of which will then be stored locally using the SQLite built into android.

The problem I am facing at the moment is making the connection from the android device to the server. I have not figured out how to pull information down yet.

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class LoginWorker {

JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> usersList;

private static String url_all_users = "http://localhost/get_user_login.php";

private static String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String TAG_USERS = "users";
private static String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static String TAG_PASSWORD = "password";

JSONArray users = null;

public void onCreate(){
    System.out.print("Login worker onCreate started");
    usersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("test","test");

    usersList.add(map);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: LoadAllUsers Running now");

    new LoadAllUsers().execute();

}

class LoadAllUsers extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args){

        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: Start of method");

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_users, "GET", params);



        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                users = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USERS);

                for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = users.getJSONObject(i);

                    String password = c.getString(TAG_PASSWORD);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                    map.put(TAG_PASSWORD, password);

                    usersList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("doInBackground : ", "No user found");
            }
        }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
        }

    protected void onPostExecution(){}
}
```

This is an example of some of the code I have been working on (For the user login). Is there a simpler way to make this connection without having to use JSON and PHP? Any help will be greatly appreciated, even if it's just links to useful blogs or tutorials!

Answer (score 0):

Follow these tutorials for connecting to mysql db and creating api which u can be used to retrieve data.

To Connect to db and create api:

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/php-restful-api-framework-slim-tutorial-1/
 https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/create-chat-app-for-android-using-gcm-1/

after creating api you can use retrofit to get data from api.

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/